# How can a management network be prevented from accessing network data?

Tags: network

I am designing a management network.

As I am entering the network from a VPN into the management network, and considering that the device has a way to bridge between the networks, how can network data be prevented from being accessed?

Comment: This question is really unclear to me. You should clarify it if possible.

Comment: This does not look like a security question but a networking question. Do you mean to ask how the *device*, which has access to both networks, be prevented from unauthorised bridging of the networks? If so, then that's just a configuration issue and no magic is involved.

Comment: most devices have the ability to cross the device. so if an user is logged into the device from network card, he can access the other network via the device. how can such network bridging be prevented !